# C++ libraries to manipulate images

Tags: c++, image, steganography

Do you know any open source/free software C++ libraries to manipulate images in these formats:
.jpg .gif .png .bmp ? The more formats it supports, the better. I am implementing a free program in C++ which hides a text file into one or more images, using [steganography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography).

I am working under Unix.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) can manipulate about anything and has interfaces for a [dozen of languages](https://imagemagick.org/script/develop.php), including the [Magick++](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/) API for C++.

Answer (score 2):

@lurks: I assume that you are looking for LSB shifting? I did some stego work a couple of years ago, and that's how it appeared most apps worked. It appears that ImageMagick (suggested by others) allows you to identify and manipulate the LSBs.

Answer (score 1):

It takes some setting up, but I'm a fan of [Adobe's GIL](http://stlab.adobe.com/gil/) (now part of [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/gil/doc/index.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [GDI](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/cgdiplusbitmap.aspx)?

-- Kevin Fairchild

Answer (score 0):

[FreeImage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/) is pretty solid. It has a C interface but is more C++-like in its implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I like [VXL](https://vxl.github.io/).

> VXL (the Vision-*something*-Libraries) is a collection of C++ libraries designed for computer vision research and implementation. It was created from TargetJr and the IUE with the aim of making a light, fast and consistent system. VXL is written in ANSI/ISO C++ and is designed to be portable over many platforms.

Answer (score 0):

For .png images you could look into Cairo (and CairoMM). There's also Anti-Grain which people consider very fast.